# No simultaneous solutions (Chinese Remainder Theorem)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem

a. Show that $x\equiv2\pmod6$ and $x\equiv3\pmod4$ have no simultaneous solutions.

If  $x\equiv2\pmod6$ then x is even but if $x\equiv3\pmod4$ then x is odd. This is a contradiction, so $x\equiv2\pmod6$ and $x\equiv3\pmod4$ have no simultaneous solutions.

b. Show that $x\equiv2\pmod6$ and $x\equiv0\pmod4$ have no simultaneous solutions.

If $x\equiv2\pmod6$ then x is even and if $x\equiv0\pmod4$ then x is a multiple of 4, so it is also even, so $x\equiv2\pmod6$ and $x\equiv0\pmod4$ have simultaneous solutions.

Comment: Think about whether x is even or odd

Comment: @user128390 how does my answer look?

Comment: In your (b) that you added, there are, in fact, simultaneous solutions -- x=20 is one.

Comment: typo! i meant have not have no oops

Comment: OK, but CRT still doesn't apply (at least not directly) in (b) because 4 and 6 aren't relatively prime

Comment: Oh...so...can I have a hint for how to reach the conclusion then?

Comment: Well, I already gave you one solution.  More generally, you are looking for k so that x=6k+2 is divisible by 4, so k for which there is a j with 6k+2=4j -- integer solutions to this equation will give solutions to the original system.  The x=20 solution corresponds to k=3, j=5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x \equiv 2\pmod{6}$, then is $x$ even or odd?

If $x \equiv 3\pmod{4}$, then is $x$ even or odd?

Do you see the contradiction?

Comment: Thanks! If x≡2(mod6) then x is even but if x≡3(mod4) then x is odd which is a contradiction, so they can have no simultaneous solutions.